# How to sort a vector using sort() in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I want to insert an element in my already sorted vector and it'll be placed at its sorted position when it'll be sorted again.
There is a function called **sort()** for sorting an array.How can I use the same function to sort a vector?
Here's my code.It gives me the compilation error.

```
//assume g1 is already sorted with some numbers        
int x;
cin >> x;
g1.push_back(x);
int s = g1.size()/g1.at(g1.begin());
//similar to int s = arr/arr[0]
sort(g1 + s,g1);
```

Comment: [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Did you consult the [manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? It comes with examples.

Comment: `sort(v.begin(), v.end())`; where `v` is the vector.

Comment: g1 is the vector object FYI. Thanks

Comment: What does `int s=g1.size()/g1.at(g1.begin());` try to do ?

Comment: and how to sort it in descending order.
I want it in descending order.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux 
sort(a,a+s).
where  s=arr/arr[0]

Comment: @RajatSingh Everyone is telling you to read the documentation for `std::sort`. It contains an example to sort in descending order! Multiple links have been provided.

Comment: @Rajat _"FYI."_ What lets you doubt we're not informed about that?

Comment: thanks everyone 
and please dont downvote as im new to vectors
Thanks

Comment: Alternativley to sorting after pushing, you could insert the value in the correct place `g1.insert( std::upper_bound( g1.begin(), g1.end(), x), x );`.

Comment: @Rajat _"as im new to vectors"_ Well, if you meet something new, read the documentation first before asking trivia here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::sort(g1.begin(), g1.end());
```

Should do the trick.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to switch out the `vector`ness of `g1` with, say, a plain array, without having to modify this code, or if this was in template code where you want to work with multiple container types, then the form

```
std::sort(std::begin(g1), std::end(g1));
```

may hold more appeal.

In any case; *Please*, do read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Or even better: `std::sort(std::begin(g1), std::end(g1));`

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ mostly a matter of taste/personal preference when not writing generic (template) code I'd say. But yes, of course, your variant *does* have its advantages.

Comment: I prefer using that form in general.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ To each his own :-) But I can certainly understand your reasoning why.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sorting, find the position where the new element should go and insert it there:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator loc = std::upper_bound(g1.begin(), g1.end(), x);
g1.insert(loc, x);
```

Or, more briefly:

```
g1.insert(std::upper_bound(g1.begin(), g1.end(), x), x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keeping it simple, let `arr` be the vector name. Write: `sort(arr.beg(),arr.end());`

(assuming already you have  written `using namespace std;`)

Comment: "arr.beg()"? That doesn't even compile.

Comment: don't forget to add #include<bits/stdc++.h>